# How to fix Join between two datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join

**Problem**: when I try to merge or join two datasets, setting the same index, it generates a datasets with duplicates.

Create the first dataframe (UNI):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import os.path

fullName=os.getcwd()
full_filename = os.path.join(fullName,'Rankings.csv')
file_stream = open(full_filename, mode='r', newline='')

reader = csv.reader(file_stream, delimiter=",")

# read and ignore the first line
header = next(reader)
data = []
# read the remaining part of the file
for i in range(2000):
info = next(reader)
data += [info]
file_stream.close()

dfUNI = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfUNI.columns = header
#I Renamed column 1 to be able to merge the two datasets with the same "Name" column
cols = dfUNI.columns.get_values()
cols[1] = 'Name'
dfUNI.columns = cols
```

Create the second dataframe (Fees):

```
full_filename = os.path.join(fullName,'Fees.csv')
file_stream = open(full_filename, mode='r',      newline='',encoding="ISO-8859-1");
#I used encoding to remove reading problems
reader = csv.reader(file_stream, delimiter=",")
# read and ignore the first line
header = next(reader)
data = []
# read the remaining part of the file
for i in range(200):
    info = next(reader)
    data += [info]
file_stream.close()

dfFees = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfFees.columns = header
del dfUNI["international"]
del dfUNI["income"]
del dfUNI["female_male_ratio"]
del dfUNI["student_staff_ratio"]
del dfUNI["year"]
dfUNI.set_index("Name")
dfFees.set_index("Name")
dfFees
```

Join them together:

```
df=dfUNI.set_index("Name")
df2=dfFees.set_index("Name")
df.join(df2,how="outer")
```

I expected a dataset with the information from the `dfFees`/`df2`" (second) dataset added in the correct rows (by `"Name"`) to the `dfUNI`/`df` (first) dataset.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, since you're using `pandas`, you may want to simplify the way you're reading in those csv's using `pd.read_csv` ([documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) (You could also use `pathlib.Path` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)) for easier path manipulation, but I focused on `pandas`):

```py
# Starting from scratch:

import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import os.path

fullName=os.getcwd()
full_filename_UNI = os.path.join(fullName, "Rankings.csv")
full_filename_Fees = os.path.join(fullName, "Fees.csv")

dfUNI  = pd.read_csv(full_filename_UNI, delimiter=",")
dfFees = pd.read_csv(full_filename_UNI, delimiter=",", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Then you can use `.rename` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)) to rename that column and `.drop` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)) instead of `del dfUNI["something"]`. Don't forget the "`inplace`" argument for either so that you don't have to redefine the variable every time like `dfUNI = dfUNI.replace(...)`.

```py
# Start of cleanup for dfUNI ->
dfUNI.rename(index=str, columns={dfUNI.columns[0]: "Name"}, inplace=True)

# Start of cleanup for dfFee ->
colNameDropList = ["international", "income", "female_male_ratio", "student_staff_ratio", "year"]
dfFees.drop(columns=colNameDropList, inplace=True)

# Set the index for both (use inplace!):
dfUNI.set_index("Name", inplace=True)
dfFees.set_index("Name", inplace=True)
```

Now comes the part that you're really looking for: you need to use a [*left join*](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types). Pandas uses a lot of SQL-esk methods for their dataframes.

```py
dfFINAL = dfUNI.join(dfFees, how="left") # "left" is the default btw
```

**OR**, instead of setting the indices beforehand, you could use the "`on`" argument of the `.join` method:

```py
dfFINAL = dfUNI.join(dfFees, how="left", on="Name")
```

You were getting duplicates because you were doing an "outer join", which throws the data together and doesn't miss any. (Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) out.)

Comment: Left join is one of 3 kinds of outer join--left, right & full. In your last paragraph you mean full (outer) join.